# accessing Data::Dumper output

Tags: perl

I have this Perl subroutine:

```
sub ask_for_lease {
        my $url      = '/sp/api/v1/lease';
        my $formdata = '{"classname":"lease",}';
        my $c = REST::Client->new();
        $c->setHost($wizhost);
        $c->PUT (
                $url
        ,       $formdata
        ,       $headers
        );
        my $r = from_json($c->responseContent());
        #print Dumper($r);
        #my @results    = $r->{'results'};
        my @items       = %{@{$r->{'results'}}[0]}->{'items'};
        print Dumper(@items);
        for my $item (@items) {

                print "=============\n";
                print Dumper($item);
                print "=============\n";
        }

}
```

It produces this output:

```
$VAR1 = [
          {
            'owner' => undef,
            'notes' => 'Simulation One',
            'version' => undef,
            'status' => 'Ready',
            'name' => 'One',
            'lease' => '7070',
            '_oid' => '1'
          },
          {
            'owner' => undef,
            'notes' => 'Simulation Two',
            'version' => undef,
            'status' => 'Ready',
            'name' => 'Two',
            'lease' => '2',
            '_oid' => '2'
          },
          {
            'owner' => undef,
            'notes' => 'Simulation Three',
            'version' => undef,
            'status' => 'Ready',
            'name' => 'Three 2012',
            'lease' => '3',
            '_oid' => '3'
          },
      ...
        ];
=============
$VAR1 = [
          {
            'owner' => undef,
            'notes' => 'Simulation One',
            'version' => undef,
            'status' => 'Ready',
            'name' => 'One',
            'lease' => '7070',
            '_oid' => '1'
          },
          {
            'owner' => undef,
            'notes' => 'Simulation Two',
            'version' => undef,
            'status' => 'Ready',
            'name' => 'Two',
            'lease' => '2',
            '_oid' => '2'
          },
          {
            'owner' => undef,
            'notes' => 'Simulation Three',
            'version' => undef,
            'status' => 'Ready',
            'name' => 'Three 2012',
            'lease' => '3',
            '_oid' => '3'
          },
      ...
        ];
=============
```

What I want to be able to do is iterate over the `items` array and print out the `status` and the `name`, but I am not sure I am dereferencing `$r` correctly.

Answer (score 3):

The line

```
my @items = %{@{$r->{'results'}}[0]}->{'items'}
```

is very suspicious. You are extracting the first element of the array referred to by `$r->{results}`, dereferencing that as a hash, and using that hash in reference syntax. You should have got

```
Using a hash as a reference is deprecated
```

if you have `use strict` and `use warnings` in place as you should.

It is best to extract complex nested data in layers. In this case you can get the reference to the `items` array into a scalar variable and use that.

```
my $items= $r->{results}[0]{items};
for my $item ( @$items ) {
  printf "name:   %s, $item->{name};
  printf "status: %s, $item->{status};
  print "--\n";
}
```

If you post your JSON data then we will be able to help much better